# Why am I getting these errors from Apache Derby?

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, derby

I run my program, the database is connected to and then it gives me two errors. One saying

```
'Schema "ROOT" does not exist'
```

and another saying

```
'Lexical error at line 1, column 8. Encountered: "@"(64), after:"".
```

Here is the code from the two SQL statements:

```
private void UpdateJTable() {
    String sql ="select idhonscores AS RowNo , Name, Characters, Kills, Deaths, Assists, XPM, CK from honscores";
    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

That is from the first error and

```
String sql3 ="SELECT "+"@rn:=@rn+1"+" AS Rank, Name, Kills 
              FROM (Select Name, sum(Kills) as Kills 
                    from honscores group by Name order by Kills DESC) t1,
                   (SELECT "+"@rn:=0"+") t2;";
```

Is for the second error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In derby the default schema is always the schema of the user you use to create the jdbc connection. I can't tell from you question, how you initialize and setup the derby database. But appending `;create=true` to the jdbc-url might help (this will create the db and schema if it does not exist).

You can [change to a different schema](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj32268.html) by executing:

```
SET SCHEMA MYSCHEMA;
```

1. The @-syntax might not be available in derby. Not everything that works in another db (especially if it is db specific) will work in derby.

Comment: Thanks, thats the most useful information I have been able to find on Derby the whole day :D

Comment: Where would I put "SET SCHEMA MYSCHEMA;"?

Comment: you have to execute it as a sql command. like a normal query.

Answer (score 0):

What has been said about username being the default schema is true. If you do not specify a username the default schema will be APP. This schema always exists.  If you connect as user root the schema "root" will not be created until you create a table in it. E.g:

```
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:memory:foo;user=root;create=true';
ij> show schemas;
TABLE_SCHEM                   
------------------------------
APP                           
NULLID                        
SQLJ                          
SYS                           
SYSCAT                        
SYSCS_DIAG                    
SYSCS_UTIL                    
SYSFUN                        
SYSIBM                        
SYSPROC                       
SYSSTAT                       

11 rows selected
ij> create table foo(i int) ;
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> show schemas;
TABLE_SCHEM                   
------------------------------
APP                           
NULLID                        
ROOT                          
SQLJ                          
SYS                           
SYSCAT                        
SYSCS_DIAG                    
SYSCS_UTIL                    
SYSFUN                        
SYSIBM                        
SYSPROC                       
SYSSTAT                       

12 rows selected
```

Wrt. @ in table and column names: That is only allowed if you quote the name containing @. E.g.:

```
ij> create table @T@(@c@ int);
ERROR 42X02: Lexical error at line 1, column 14.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
ij> create table "@T@"("@c@" int);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into "@T@" values (0),(1),(2);
3 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> select * from "@T@";
@c@        
-----------
0          
1          
2          

3 rows selected
```

Note however, that when quoting a name it becomes case-sensitive. So in the previous example the following fails:

```
ij> select * from "@t@";
ERROR 42X05: Table/View '@t@' does not exist.
```

because in quotes, @T@ and @t@ are considered different names.